# Promql - Labels conjunction (and) in expression

Tags: prometheus, promql

Say I have the following expression:

```
metric_a{first_name!~"John", last_name~!"Doe"}
```

This will result in all metric_a's values whose first name is not John OR their last name is not Doe, meaning that the following values won't be part of the result:

```
metric_a{first_name="John", last_name="Johnson"}
metric_a{first_name="Sam", last_name="Doe"}
```

Is it possible to filter out only John Doe?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do `metric_a unless metric_a{first_name="John",last_name="Doe"}`

Comment: Can you explain why you think this doesn't answer the question? It will filter out John Doe, as requested, and more efficiently than the answer.

Comment: You're right! My bad. Thanks for pointing it out. I removed my comment. I thought that your question did not provide an answer, because it already had 1 downvote, is missing an explanation of why and how your answer works and due to short length.

Answer (score 0):

A simple

```
metric_a{first_name!~"John"} or  metric_a{last_name~!"Doe"}
```

will do apparently